# catch(...) does not catch all exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

I've run into a problem regarding exceptions.

The code is shown below,

```
try
{
    auto it = set_difference(allInterfaces.begin(), allInterfaces.end(), eths.begin(),   
    eths.end(), newCards.begin());
}  
catch(...)
{
  cout << "exception thrown << endl;
}
```

I know set_difference() is throwing an exception but the programs exits and the catch block doesn't catch the exception.  Is there a way to catch the exception?  I thought the catch all should always work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exception do you think `set_difference` is throwing?

Comment: Remember that some things are *called* exceptions, but they are system (or processor) exceptions and not C++ exceptions. The `catch` block only catches C++ exceptions from `throw`, not any other kind of exceptions (like for example null-pointer access might lead to).

Comment: The program exited when vector newCards was too small.  I got this error : *** glibc detected *** /networking: free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000153d4a8 ***.  Maybe this is not an exception at all then.

Comment: @Smithy: Post the error message.

Comment: @Smithy It is not an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_difference` will write the elements that are unique to either of the input sets to the output range you pass in. It's your responsibility to ensure that that range is large enough to contain the result. Otherwise, you'll walk off beyond the bounds of the range, resulting in **undefined behavior**. No exception is thrown when this happens, the best indicator you can hope for is an assertion failure in unoptimized builds (and there's no guarantee for that either).

Assuming `newCards` is a container that supports `push_back`, the easiest way to prevent this is to use [`std::back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), which will call `push_back` every time an object is assigned to it.

```
auto it = set_difference(allInterfaces.begin(), allInterfaces.end(), 
                         eths.begin(), eths.end(), std::back_inserter(newCards));
```

The other options available are [`std::front_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/front_insert_iterator) (calls `push_front()`) and [`std::insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) (calls `insert()`). Choose the one that suits your needs best.

Comment: Thanks, that's an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of your comment, it's very likely that you increase and iterate the iterator returned from `newCards.begin()`, even beyond the bounds of the vector. This leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which in your case causes a crash) and not to a thrown C++ exception. Iterator access is not bounds-checked in C++ (very few things are).

To solve this you need to pass in the end of the `newCards` vector as well, and make sure you don't step out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.  I need to redesign the code to stop this problem from happening.